# Javascript - Display 'loading' message with getContent

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Im using Javascript to display and populate some drop downs with data, something like:

```
getContent(url, bindOptionResults);
```

How can I display a loading message while the 'getContent' gets the content in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to your dropdown.

```
$('#DDList').prepend('<option>Loading..</option>');
```